Moviepy write_videofile() cannot write to AWS lambda's /tmp/ directory
Just trying to create a clip in moviepy, write it to the /tmp/ location in AWS lambda, to then upload to S3. The following code, for audio, works completely fine:
clip = AudioFileClip(self.local_file_name).subclip(offset_start, offset_end)
self.clip_path = f'/tmp/{uuid_str}.{self.file_type}'
clip.write_audiofile(self.clip_path)

Same code, but for video, is failing on clip.write_videofile():
clip = VideoFileClip(self.local_file_name).subclip(offset_start, offset_end)
self.clip_path = f'/tmp/{uuid_str}.{self.file_type}'
clip.write_videofile(self.clip_path)

clip.write_videofile() returns:
FFMPEG encountered the following error while writing file 955cb5714023413b8aed962864c3043cTEMP_MPY_wvf_snd.mp3:
b'955cb5714023413b8aed962864c3043cTEMP_MPY_wvf_snd.mp3: Read-only file system\

How come writing an audiofile is completely fine, but it can't do the videofile?
My ephemeral storage is the max at 10240 mb, plenty of space. The full length video clip is only 36.59 MB, so I would imagine a subclip is just a fraction of this.

The tmp audiofile being generated under the hood by moviepy wasn't writing to /tmp/. Also, had to add some codec params AND set the temp_audiofile extension to .m4a, for it to keep audio, otherwise it was generating a silent vid.
clip = VideoFileClip(self.local_file_name).subclip(offset_start, offset_end) 
clip.write_videofile(self.clip_path, temp_audiofile=f'/tmp/{part}.m4a', remove_temp=True, codec="libx264", audio_codec="aac")

